# How can I handle different views in one game loop?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, view, surfaceview

I'm making a game in android, and I have two clases which extends SurfaceView (TitleView and GameView). Too I have a GameLoopThread that I initialize in the TitleView that draws all my bitmaps in this View, but it only works in this view. So when I want to change to the GameView, how I only initialize the GameLoopThread in the TitleView and not in the GameView, this last is a black screen because nothing is drawed on it.

Someone can help me?

This is my GameLoopThread class:

```
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {

    static final long FPS = 25;
    //private GameView view;
    private TitleView tview;
    private boolean running = false;

    public GameLoopThread(TitleView titleView) {
        this.tview = titleView;
    }

    public void setRunning(Boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                c = tview.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (tview.getHolder()) {
                    tview.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    tview.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                } else {
                    sleep(25);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sergio,  I have an application that is doing something similar, video view then picture view but I have each in a different activity class, the main activity is the video view then when videos are done it starts the picture activity.  if this is what you are trying to do,

start you title view by calling sartActivity,

private static final int TITILE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

```
    Intent titleIntent = new Intent(GameViewActivity.this, TitleViewActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, TITLE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

once the title activity is done, call the following from your tile activity, that should terminate your title activity and restart your game view,

```
          setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
          finish();
```

in your game activity view use this method to receive the notification that the title view is done,

```
 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
    if (requestCode == TITLE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) //* notification from titleview 
    {
      switch (resultCode) 
      {
          case Activity.RESULT_OK:
              //* do something,
              break;
```

This code works perfectly for my application, let me know if you have any other questions.